# in flink,how to store mutiple k-v and match them while mapping

Tags: java, bigdata, apache-flink

there are userID and cardID.When data comes,store it if it cant match cardID, or check its userID.when the user is not match,print a warn including userIDs and cardID.

I try to store them in

```
class Bean{
  String userID;
  String cardID;
}
```

```
Liststate<Bean> liststate;
```

I can store them,just dont know how to match.

Comment: I couldn't understand the question. What happens if CardId matches. What does "store it" means?  What does "or" mean ? Do you store data if the cardId doesn`t match or check the userId?

Comment: when two users are bound to the same cardID,print a warning.So I store userid and cardid,I dont know how to match them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don`t need to store k-v.
Key your stream by cardId and in keyedProcessFunction keep a state for UserId.
If incoming userId is not same with the userId in the value state, create warning message.